# Reverse group by linq

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

I have the fallowing code:

```
 var groups =
          from w in wordsAndFec
          group w by  w.Value;
      foreach (var group in groups).....
```

In the code above w.Value is an int and the code will later add the groups to a string. However i need to also reverse the order so that the code groups by highest to lowest value instead of lowest to highest.

Non working example of what needs to be done:

```
from w in wordsAndFec
group w by w.value orderby reverse;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orderby` takes a value to sort on:

```
group w by w.value into g
orderby g.Key descending
select g;
```

Comment: That code yield an error. Can you elaborate? Nevermind Jeff's edit fixed it